# how to combine /&nbsp;/g and /<[^>]+>/gm, with angularJs?

Tags: angularjs

how to combine `/&nbsp;/g` and `/<[^>]+>/gm`, with angularJs?
this is my code:

```
.filter('htmlToPlaintext',function(){
        return function(text) {
            return  text ? String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '') : '';
        }
    })
```